# Simple, typesafe consumption of an API in Typescript

Tags: typescript, api, interface, type-safety, typesafe

I struggled with naming this question - open to changing it.

I'm fairly new to typescript, and I'm trying to consume an API in a generic, typesafe, and very extensible way.

Taking inspiration from [RESTyped](https://github.com/rawrmaan/restyped), I've defined a generic "API definition" interface:

```
interface ApiBase {
    [route: string]: ApiRoute   
}

interface ApiRoute {
    query: { [key: string]: string }
    body: any
    response: any
}

interface ApiSpec {
    [route: string]: {
        [method: string]: ApiRoute  
    }
}
```

and this can be used to define the types for multiple API endpoints, like so:

```
interface MyApi extends ApiSpec {
    "/login": {
        "POST": {
            body: {
                username: string,
                password: string
            },
            response: {
                token: string
            }   
        }   
    },
    "/user": {
        "GET": {
            query: {
                "username": string
            },
            response: {
                "email": string,
                "name": string
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I suspect that it's possible for a generic class to consume these types, and provide type-safe methods for them. Something like:

```
const api = ApiService<MyApi>();
api.post("/login", {
    // This body is typesafe - won't compile if it doesn't match the spec
    username: "johnny99",
    password: "hunter2"
});
```

Where the `post()` method won't compile if the object doesn't match the `body` defined in the `MyApi` interface.

Unfortunately, I'm pretty lost for where to go from here. Something like this:

```
class ApiService<T> {
    post(route: string, body: T[route].body): T[route].response {
        // todo
    }
}
```

Which obviously doesn't compile. How can I access the subtype in the `MyApi` interface? `T[route].body` is definitely wrong. How do I do this?

Cheers

EDIT ------------------------------------------

I did some reading, and I think I'm getting somewhere!

This works on the typescript playground:

```
class ApiService<API extends ApiSpec> {
    async post<Path extends Extract<keyof API, string>>(
        route: Path,
        data: API[Path]["POST"]["body"]
    ): Promise<API[Path]["response"]> {
        const resp = await fetch(route, {
            method: "POST",
            body: JSON.stringify(data),
        });
        return await resp.json();
    }
}
```

And works perfectly when calling a route that exists:

```
const api = new ApiService<MyApi>();

// Will give an error if the wrong "body" is passed in!
api.post("/login", {
    username: "johnny99",
    password: "rte"
});
```

but it *also* works when calling a route that doesn't exist, which is not what I want to happen.

```
// Should error, but doesn't!
api.post("/bad", {
    whatever: ""
});
```

I'm also a bit worried about my `post()` implementation – what happens when the object given by `resp.json()` is different to what's defined in the type definition? Will it throw a runtime error – should I always call it in `try/catch` guards, or can I somehow make the Promise fail instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I get to the answer, I tried to reproduce your situation in the Playground and noticed I needed to change the type of `ApiRoute` to

```
interface ApiRoute {
  query?: { [key: string]: string }; // optional
  body?: any; // optional
  response: any;
}
```

to avoid errors.  If that wasn't an error for you, it's because you're not using `--strictNullChecks`, which you really should.  I will assume we're doing strict null checking from now on.

---

I think your problem here is that your `ApiSpec` interface says that it has `ApiRoute` properties for *every possible key* and *every posible subkey*:

```
declare const myApi: MyApi;
myApi.mumbo.jumbo; // ApiRoute
myApi.bad.POST.body; // any
```

That code isn't an error. So, when you call

```
api.post("/bad", {
  whatever: ""
});
```

you are essentially just looking up the `body` property of some `myApi.bad.POST`, which is not an error.

---

So how do we fix this?  I think it might make more sense to express the type of `ApiSpec`  as a *generic constraint* on possible `MyApi`-like types instead of a concrete type with a pair of nested index signatures:

```
type EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<A extends object> = {
  [P in keyof A]: { [M in keyof A[P]]: ApiRoute }
};
```

That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) which turns an `A` like `{foo: {bar: number, baz: string}}` into `{foo: {bar: ApiRoute, baz: ApiRoute}}`.  So if you have an `A extends EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<A>`, then you know `A` meets your intended specifications (more or less... I think you might think of making sure each property of `A` is itself an `object`  type).

And you don't need to say `MyApi extends ApiSpec`.   You can just leave it like

```
interface MyApi { /* ... */ }
```

and if it's bad it won't be accepted by `ApiService`.  Or, if you want to know right away, you could do it like this:

```
interface MyApi extends EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<MyApi> { /* ... */ }
```

Now to define `ApiService`.  Before we get there, let's make some type helpers we'll use shortly.  First, `PathsForMethod<A, M>` takes an api type `A` and a method name `M`, and returns the list of string-valued paths that support that method:

```
type PathsForMethod<A extends EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<A>, M extends keyof any> = {
  [P in keyof A]: M extends keyof A[P] ? (P extends string ? P : never) : never
}[keyof A];
```

And then `Lookup<T, K>`:

```
type Lookup<T, K> = K extends keyof T ? T[K] : never;
```

is basically `T[K]` except if the compiler can't verify that `K` is a key of `T`, it returns `never` instead of giving a compiler error.  This will be useful because the compiler isn't smart enough to realize that `A[PathsForMethod<A, "POST">]` has a `"POST"` key, even though that's how `PathsForMethod` was defined.  It's a bit of a wrinkle we have to overcome.

Okay, here's the class:

```
class ApiService<A extends EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<A>> {
  async post<P extends PathsForMethod<A, "POST">>(
    route: P,
    data: Lookup<A[P], "POST">["body"]
  ): Promise<Lookup<A[P], "POST">["response"]> {
    const resp = await fetch(route, {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data)
    });
    return await resp.json();
  }
}
```

Going over that... we constrain `A` to `EnsureAPIMeetsSpec<A>`.  We then constrain the `route` parameter to be only those paths in `PathsForMethod<A, "POST">`.  This will automatically exclude the `"/bad"` `route` you tried in your code.  Finally we can't just do `A[P]["POST"]` without compiler error, so we do `Lookup<A[P], "POST">` instead, and it works fine:

```
const api = new ApiService<MyApi>(); // accepted

const loginResponse = api.post("/login", {
  username: "johnny99",
  password: "rte"
});
// const loginResponse: Promise<{ token: string; }>

api.post("/bad", { // error!
  whatever: ""
}); // "/bad" doesn't work
```

---

That's the way I'd proceed to start with.  After that you might want to narrow down your definition of `ApiSpec` and `ApiRoute`.  For example, perhaps you want two types of `ApiRoute`, some of which require `body` and others prohibit it.  And you can likely represent your http methods as some union of string literals like `"POST" | "GET" | "PUT" | "DELETE" | ...` and narrow down `ApiSpec` so that `"POST"` methods require `body` while `"GET"` methods prohibit it, etc.  This would possibly make it easier for the compiler to ensure that you only call `post()` on the right paths and that the `body` of such posts will be required and defined instead of possibly undefined.

Anyway, hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play//#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUD2BXSZAbwFgAoZZARz2gE8B+ALmOQG0BrCOlgZzCigA5gF0+A4cgC+AbnKUARjgAmjFnBB05FZFAi90OELwjrN2qeXJg66FAFFjePagAKASQCyECGF4BlOwQAHlRkCAAPSBBlXmQcBQArCAQwAD5kAF5ieXZXZFBkLjocGDQxVjZPApAi7lK0NlcRCoxsfEJLMlkrMlBIWEQUTzo28KiIGLjHXmcINy8fP0CU4JG2jNIdACIAegAbHCFQbZYtykpXAHl-ABUz3IvkJVUHnSfKPBMoEDgAW1MyH4ghAQm0Hwu6DgvF4AHccFBlOIQWDHhceu8LnoDEYTG8IZQwDguCBkcJwR8MU8qdIKXsvtBTjlMQBxez3ZkQmj0fEEhk-f6A4HktGUGlPbGGYyA84EiB-ODAfZk0EUiG-AEq1GYsVq2m5DFday2FCuOBgAAWvAAYgjvJaVKFxtFYsgZnMFt5fAEgqE0gAaZDVSIuuLFBoaOgZbKypo1OolMqoCrBiZTBMNVBNETIBjIAAU+RDk1dwtBueQ+RYIAgADdoABKZDVuvQchSTj1JMibTGuzIAAyOGJeHQwVugYA0tHkJPnSWw13kLcK7c2JOcy361Be2QEPtoXE2v5oLXgEgncX0+6XB4vctfag0ptctC6CAEMhDPxgkW066zUtG07V8C1HVQQNtmuO5tmffM0SgDpAVcf00WUc04BYIcRzHLNmkg6DblgththeOhthEXIGxYVxEL+YATGCbCOFHUJswIm4iLSEjJVxCAKJfTEEFxMBdH0dAsmQOBYUVUSYF8BALXzRCCAgQNZSeAEHSRZAoM47ZUJ1Z4VB4ZAACl-CuAA5AA6MtjhgOh83QsA4AbNEpAbPU9DAZxamk2SxIMGzEl4Ix8y8g1216YTjFEuBMEkmtYTQTATygM8L3WTA0gi3dYv4ZBDmOEAsHEvjJIS4AbO-MB8z2YqTnU3J+Q1QFtkSHALRATQAE5eoM3IoRheFERYbYoEgbZ20ishdl2ZACtExrSvK6UaLohiIGCIhkCJEktRkaQ0l6Kqapwfh6t2BQ4GUAzWHm8IoEQqAAEJclhC1zVbKBxum7ovOQR69huu7kGUHB9BAAByUTRo4cggA)

Comment: This is fantastic! Thanks for your help - there's a bunch of fancy stuff I learned from this, like the `PathsForMethod` - its basically like programming with variables but instead of variables, it's generic types. Super cool!